# Backbone routing - direct URL

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, backbone-routing

I'm building an app where I have a server that works on REST API and returns me list of users.
I build an backbone module where I render the list of user I get from the server and display it on a page. I question the server about the users according to date, for example -
`http://localhost/getUsers/20021989/20021990` - So I get only the users that were born between those dates.
I added the backbone router that each time that I choose a date it navigates to a function getUsers(start, end):

```
routes: {
    "getUsers/:start/:end": "getUsersPreview",
    },
```

and the function is:

```
 getUsersPreview: function(start, end) {
      some code here
 }
```

The event is fired whenever I press the button, but when I copy-paste the URL into other tab (`http://localhost/#getUsers/20021989/20021990`) - It just redirects to the main page or something.

I'm using also Laravel framework for the server side coding.

Answer (score 0):

When a Router is created, you should call Backbone.history.start() to begin monitoring hashchange events, and dispatching routes. Have you called it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this -
var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start({root: '/public/'});
It all works great except from the address bar.